# Kinect audio on windows

Tags: audio, kinect

Is there a way to access Kinect's microphone array on Windows without using the official MS SDK? I know it doesn't work in OpenNI and it seems that it probably never will. I also tried OpenKinect/libfreenect library, but I was not able to compile with audio support, only without it.

I haven't found any examples of recording audio using Kinect on Windows (except MS SDK of course). Is this even possible? Maybe with some workaround similar to controlling Kinect's motor from OpenNI like [this](http://groups.google.com/group/openni-dev/browse_thread/thread/19bba04f8cb743db)?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand the Kinect just shows up as a multi-channel audio input device, which you should be able to access using [WASAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371455%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [DirectSound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) directly without the need for the Kinect SDK.

You could also use a cross platform API like [PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/).

Comment: I guess I probably mixed up the terms "library" and "driver". I think the microphone shows up as input device when using MSSDK driver only. However, this MSSDK driver (unlike OpenNI Primesense/avin and CL NUI camera drivers) limits the sensor to min depth of 0.8 meters. So my question is in fact is it even possible to use Kinect audio on windows and not be limited by the MS depth restriction? That is with the Xbox version of the sensor of course.